# How to create a Function to update , delete or insert dynamically in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

My scenario is this. i have a telephone table that needs to be updated (incase they need to change the existing one for the client) or delete (incase they wish to delete the existing number) or insert (incase the field is empty n a new no is inserted).
i already have two stored procedures which adds a new telephone and updates an existing one. whose parameters are:

```
 EXECUTE @RC = [CUSTOMER_test].[dbo].[uspAddClientTel] 
   @ClientID
  ,@TelNo
  ,@TelTypeID
  ,@DetailsTypeID
  ,@SortNo
  ,@ResultTelID OUTPUT 

EXECUTE @RC = [CUSTOMER_test].[dbo].[uspUpdateClientTel] 
   @TelID
  ,@TelNo
  ,@TelTypeID
  ,@DetailsTypeID
  ,@SortNo
  ,@ResultTelID OUTPUT
GO
```

a part of the query in form view

```
  (SELECT TOP 1 F.tel_no FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id = @id ORDER BY sort_no ) AS fax, 
(SELECT TOP 1 T.tel_no from TELEPHONE as T where T.tel_type_id = 1 OR T.tel_type_id = 2 AND T.client_id = @id ORDER BY sort_no) AS telephone, 
(SELECT TOP 1 F.tel_id FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id = @id ORDER BY sort_no ) AS faxid , 
(SELECT TOP 1 T.tel_id from TELEPHONE as T where T.tel_type_id = 1 OR T.tel_type_id = 2 AND T.client_id = @id ORDER BY sort_no) AS telephoneid ,
CLIENT_ADDRESS.client_address_id

  FROM ORGANIZATION AS O INNER JOIN CLIENT ON O.client_id = CLIENT.client_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_ADDRESS ON  CLIENT.client_id = CLIENT_ADDRESS.client_id
 WHERE (CLIENT.client_id = @id)"
```

so i have the telephone (as landline/mobile ) and the fax along with their IDs , if they already exist in the DB.

Now i need to create a function which takes in the arguments and thereby decides which sp to use depending on the arguments passed to it.
I'm completely lost here. any help on how to go about this function will be much appreciated. even links to tutorials will help!
thanks again!

p.s
before trying the function i did something like this , but its not consistent

```
protected void FrmClient_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string TelTypeID;
    string ResultTelID1 = "";

    int intClientID = (int)e.Keys[0];
    string strTelID = (string)e.OldValues["telephoneid"];
    string strFaxID = (string)e.OldValues["faxid"];


     SqlConnection conTel = new SqlConnection();
    conTel.ConnectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CUSTOMERConnectionString"]);
    conTel.Open();

    if (strTelID != "")
    {
        string strtelcmd = ("SELECT tel_type_id, details_type_id, sort_no from TELEPHONE where tel_id =" + strTelID);
        SqlCommand telcmd = new SqlCommand(strtelcmd, conTel);
        SqlDataReader rdrTel = telcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdrTel.Read())
        {

            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["TelTypeID"].DefaultValue = rdrTel["tel_type_id"].ToString();
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["DetailsTypeID"].DefaultValue = rdrTel["details_type_id"].ToString();
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["SortNo"].DefaultValue = rdrTel["sort_no"].ToString();

        }
        rdrTel.Close();

    }


    else   if (strFaxID != "")
    {
        string strfaxcmd = ("SELECT tel_type_id, details_type_id, sort_no from TELEPHONE where tel_id ="+ strFaxID);
        SqlCommand faxcmd = new SqlCommand(strfaxcmd, conTel);
        SqlDataReader rdrfax = faxcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdrfax.Read())
        {
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["TelTypeID1"].DefaultValue = rdrfax["tel_type_id"].ToString();
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["DetailsTypeID1"].DefaultValue = rdrfax["details_type_id"].ToString();
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["SortNo1"].DefaultValue = rdrfax["sort_no"].ToString();
        }

        rdrfax.Close();

    }
    else if (strTelID == "")
    {

        SqlCommand cmdaddTel = new SqlCommand("uspAddClientTel",conTel);
        cmdaddTel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        string strNewTel = (string)e.NewValues["telephone"]; 


        if (strNewTel.Trim().StartsWith("06") || strNewTel.Trim().StartsWith("07") )

            TelTypeID = "2";
        else
            TelTypeID = "1";


        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientID", intClientID));
        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelNo",strNewTel ));
        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelTypeID", TelTypeID));
        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DetailsTypeID", 1));
        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortNo1", 1 ));
        cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResultTelID1", ResultTelID1));

        SqlDataReader rdrAddFax = cmdaddTel.ExecuteReader();

    }

    else if (strFaxID == "")
    {

        SqlCommand cmdaddFax = new SqlCommand("uspAddClientTel", conTel);
        cmdaddFax.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        string strNewFax = (string)e.NewValues["fax"];



        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientID", intClientID));
        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelNo", strNewFax));
        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelTypeID", 3));
        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DetailsTypeID", 2));
        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortNo1", 1));
        cmdaddFax.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResultTelID1", ResultTelID1));

        SqlDataReader rdrAddFax = cmdaddFax.ExecuteReader();
    }


    conTel.Close();


}
```

and the sps in the updatecommand of formview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi all i worked it out at the end. thought it might help beginner like me

```
  public void functUAD(int intClientID, string TelType, int TelID, string OldTelNumber, string NewTelNumber)
    {
        int ResultTelID = 0 ;
        int TelTypeID ;
        int Result= 0 ;


        SqlConnection conTel = new SqlConnection();
        conTel.ConnectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CUSTOMERConnectionString"]);
        conTel.Open();

        if (TelType.ToLower() == "fax")

            TelTypeID = 3;

        else if (NewTelNumber.Trim().StartsWith("06") || NewTelNumber.Trim().StartsWith("07"))

            TelTypeID = 2;
        else
            TelTypeID = 1;



       if (OldTelNumber != "" && NewTelNumber != "" )    //update old number with new number
        {


            SqlCommand cmdUpdateTel = new SqlCommand("uspUpdateClientTel", conTel);
            cmdUpdateTel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlCommand cmdSortNo = new SqlCommand("SELECT sort_no FROM TELEPHONE WHERE tel_id= " + TelID, conTel);
            string SortNo = (string)cmdSortNo.ExecuteScalar();


            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelID", TelID));
            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelNo", NewTelNumber));
            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelTypeID", TelTypeID));
            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DetailsTypeID", 1));
            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortNo", SortNo));
            cmdUpdateTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResultTelID", ResultTelID));

            cmdUpdateTel.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        if (OldTelNumber == "" && NewTelNumber != "")   // add a newnumber
        {

            int SortNo = 0 ;
            SqlCommand cmdaddTel = new SqlCommand("uspAddClientTel", conTel);
            cmdaddTel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            if (TelTypeID == 1)
                SortNo = 1;
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmdSortNo = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(sort_no) from TELEPHONE where tel_id =" + TelID, conTel);
                int MaxSort = (int)cmdSortNo.ExecuteScalar();
                SortNo += MaxSort;
            }
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientID", intClientID));
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelNo", NewTelNumber));
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelTypeID", TelTypeID));
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DetailsTypeID", 1));
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortNo", SortNo ));
            cmdaddTel.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResultTelID", ResultTelID));

            cmdaddTel.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        if (OldTelNumber != "" && NewTelNumber == "") // delete the old number
        {

            SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("RemoveClientTel", conTel);
            cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TelID",TelID));
            cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Result", Result));
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

and then you can call the function with appropriate parameters! bye!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not incorporate this logic into the SP?  So depending on the parameters passed to the SP you either insert or update the necessary records?

I know you suggest you want this to be done in the business logic, but as you don't appear to be using an ORM for your data access layer you may as well keep id fast (as you will only have to do a single round trip to the db) and tidy in the SP?

Comment: The sp's are already created and i need to use them...so the only option is to go by a function!